# CUSTOMER and purchased CATEGORY count details in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the below require. if anyone provide the solution it would be thankful

Requirements:-

Transaction of the customer who purchased in the below category
[Customers and purchased Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufrwm.png)

Total Number of customer from category level
[category and customer count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bP4O.png)

I want to display the output life below
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rOMH.png)

Thanks
R Sanjay

Comment: Please, show your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cte`, self join it and join it again with your table as following:

```
With cte as 
(Select category, count(1) as cnt
From your_table
Group by category)
Select t1.category,
T1.cnt,
T2.category,
T2.cnt,
Count(distinct t.customer) as both_cat
From cte t1
Join cte t2 
On (t1.category <> t2.category)
Join your_table t
On (t.category in (t1.category, t2.category)
Group by t1.category, t2.category,
         T1.cnt, t2.cnt
Order by t1.category, t2.category
```

Cheers!!

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: Accepted it Thanks Tejash